# Vagrant "box" vs "base box", is there a difference?

Tags: vagrant

The Vagrant documentation and CLI use the terms "box" and "base box". The naming implies a base box is a specific type of box, however, the terms seem to be used as synonyms. Is there a difference between Vagrant "box" and Vagrant "base box"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a description of *Base Box* according to https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html:

> There are a special category of boxes known as "base boxes." These boxes contain the bare minimum required for Vagrant to function, are generally not made by repackaging an existing Vagrant environment (hence the "base" in the "base box").
>
> For example, the Ubuntu boxes provided by the Vagrant project (such as "precise64") are base boxes. They were created from a minimal Ubuntu install from an ISO, rather than repackaging an existing environment.

So while "base box" is still a "box", it's just more accurate term, clearly emphasizing some initial OS state with minimal set of software installed.

Comment: I purchased the book "Vagrant: Up and Running" and read the chapter on boxes to gain more insight. Boxes may be created from existing boxes or from scratch (e.g. from a machine you create in VirtualBox). Those created from scratch are base boxes.